# using lottie.js gives error TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: react-native

i have created a loader animation i have install lottie.js and then i download loader.json file and then i created component ActivityIndicatior like this

```
import React from "react";
import LottieView from "lottie-react-native";

function ActivityIndicator({ visible = false }) {
  if (!visible) return null;

  return (
    <LottieView autoPlay loop source={require("../animation/loader.json")} />
  );
}

export default ActivityIndicator;
```

and then i import this in listing screen and i define it  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

```
export default function ListingsScreens({ navigation }) {
  const [listings, setListing] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadListings();
  }, []);
  const loadListings = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await listingApi.getListings();
    setLoading(false);

    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

    setError(false);

    setListing(response.data);
  };
  return (
    <ExpoScreen style={styles.screen}>
      {error && (
        <>
          <AppText> Could not retrieve the listings</AppText>
          <Button title="retry" onPress={loadListings} />
        </>
      )}
      <ActivityIndicator visible={true} />
      {/* <FlatList
        data={listings}
        keyExtractor={(listings) => listings.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CardList
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={"$" + item.price}
            imageUrl={item.images[0].url}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ListingDetails", item)}
          />
        )}
      /> */}
    </ExpoScreen>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using [**`react-native-animated-loader`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-loader), which uses Airbnb's Lottie for beautiful loader animations.

Comment: this is animated loader from lottie

Comment: I've encountered some problems while using `Lottie`, since you would like to animate a JSON file so you can use this. In my case, it has worked like a charm.

Comment: what should i do tell me briefly

Comment: Just, follow the instructions the package described.

Comment: The question isn't clear, and as I am seeing the code is okay.
Maybe the package is not installed correctly,

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I thing the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 14):

Restarting your server resolves the error. I also had this same issue.

Comment: Same issue as OP can confirm restarting expo server worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest version of the lottie-react-native. Upgrading to 3.4.0 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

**I was facing the same issue and I solved it by just prettifying my lottie-react-native/lib/LottieView.js file.**

[image]